# Why does a cart get added with no Order Number?

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce2, cart

Sometimes, the cart gets added without the id as below.
[image: cart with no id]

Any ideas, please?

(Craft Commerce version is 2.2.19)

Comment: I'm assuming this is Craft Commerce? If so, what version?

Comment: @Brad Bell, Craft commerce version is 2.2.19